# Style text option in dropdown select

Tags: css

I'm just trying to apply some basic styles to different options in a dropdown select element. In Firefox, the styles work, but in Chrome and IE9 the styles don't take effect, even though in Chrome I can see in the debug inspector that the styles are being read and not overridden by any other styles. Any ideas?

E.g this rule:

```
select option.depth-0 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

On this element:

```
<option value="1" class="depth-0">Home</option>
```

Comment: I think the only way is to style the `select` element (i.e. no control over individual items)...

Comment: Check out below Stackoveflow link you may get your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895476/287100

Comment: Given up and have gone for indentation instead. The reason for trying to do this was to show a hierarchical structure

Comment: You can show hierarchical structure using `OPTGROUP` element.

Answer (score 2):

Swap `select` and `option` selectors in your css:

```
option.depth-0 select{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Edit**

Option `select` element actually not part of browser. It is part of OS. It difficult to style.

For example you can't change `height` of some `option` in `select` element. Changing `font-weight` assumed that too.

The only option I see is to create your own custom `select` element. Using JavaScript for example. Then you can customize it as you need using CSS. And it will be crossbrowser.